# Find multiple matching values in column 1, then get their MIN corresponding values from column 3

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find values that occur more than once in Column 1, then get their MIN corresponding values from column 3. So for example if column 1 has 3 matching values of 124L, and their corresponding values in column 3 is 120, 90 and 60, then overwrite column 3 of the matching values with the 60. So at the end of the day all my 124L should have 60 in Column 3.

I would appreciate any help or direction, am currently stumped especially on the searching for multiple matching values. Thank you. Below is the code which am ashamed to even post...

```
  Sub minFinder()

  'declare variables
   Dim minCartMx As Long, multiLocsCartMxFound As Long
   Dim searchMultiLocs As Range, foundMultiLocs As Range
   Dim FinalRow As Long
   FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To FinalRow
  'search multiple occurances of values in column 1
   Set searchMultiLocs = Cells(i, 1)
   For Each searchMultiLocs In searchMultiLocs

  'I dont think this works but am trying to get values of corresponding  
   'to foundMultiLocs in column 3 (cells(i,3)

  Set multiLocsCartMxFound = searchMultiLocs.Find(what:=searchMultiLocs, 
  LookIn:=xlWhole, _ searchorder:=xlByRows, searchDirection:=xlNext, _ 
  MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)


  'determine the minumum value of column 3 of the foundMultiLocs
  minCartMx = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(multiLocsCartMxFound)

' overwrite the column 3 of the matching values with MIN
  minCartMx = Cells(i, 3)


 End Sub
```

enter code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Find` only returns a single cell. Use `Evaluate` instead to find the minimum value. This example returns the minimum value from column C where column A is `"value"`.

```
minValue = Application.Evaluate("min(if(A1:A10 = ""value"",  C1:C10, """"))")
```

Also, on the last line of your code, your operands are flipped. You meant to write `Cells(i,3) = minCartmx`

Answer (score 1):

In Vba:

```
Sub minFinder()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim minRng As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet5") 'Change to your sheet

With ws
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set minRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
End With
For Each cel In rng
    cel.Offset(, 2).Value = ws.Evaluate("=MIN(IF(" & cel.Address(0, 0) & "=" & rng.Address(0, 0) & "," & minRng.Address(0, 0) & "))")
Next cel


End Sub
```

---

But you could easily do this with the formula from the code only.

in an empty column put:

```
=MIN(IF(A2=$A$2:$A$7,$C$2:$C$7))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with ctrl-Shift-Enter.

[image]

Then it is just a matter of copying and pasting the values.